# Elegant way to parse indented strings

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm writing a small text parser in Python and trying to parse lines into lists. I'm parsing a file line by line.

Most of the data is flat, but some is hierarchical with the following structure:

```
1, -1
    2, 2, 0, -33017.1, 21011.3, 97.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, -1, 0, -36936.3, 21672.3, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 3, 0, -33220.8, 21150.6, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 4, 0, -33515.6, 21272.7, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 5, 0, -33832, 21314.3, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 6, 0, -35112, 21314.3, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0
    2, 7, 0, -36072, 21314.3, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 8, 0, -36388.3, 21356, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    2, 1, 0, -36683.1, 21478.1, 96.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    1, 0, 0, -32888.9, 20917.9, 99, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    1, 1, 0, -37066, 21772.1, 96.6008, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

I'd like to parse it such that the resulting list looks like:

```
[1, -1, [[2, 2, 0, -33017.1, 21011.3, 97.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], ...]]
```

The section only has one level of indentation.

Most techniques I've tried so far feel crude - such as iterating over the number of indented lines to get a count, and then slicing using indexes, and then iterating once more. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of regular expressions. Most of the data has a very simple structure; this is the most complicated bit to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of `for line in file` and then `if line.startswith('\t')` or some other white space character? Then you could add to your list `data.append(line.split())` and for the rest of the lines, `data.extend(line.split())`

```
data = []
for line in file:
    if line.startswith(' '):
        data.append([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')])
    else:
        data.extend([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')])
```

(Unable to access python right now, so untested)
With regards to the original question, you may want to replace `item.strip()` with `int(item.strip())`  or `float(item.strip())` as you wanted the result to be numbers

```
data = []
startindent = False
for line in file:
    if startindent:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            indent.append([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')])
        else: # if we were previously in 'indent' mode but this line isn't, add our collected data and add this line as normal
            startindent = False
            data.append(indent)
            data.extend([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')])
        continue

    if line.startswith(' '):
        startindent = True
        # .. signify that the line is indented
        indent = [] # list to hold indented text
        indent.append([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]) # add the current line to this indented list
    else:
        startindent = False
        data.extend([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]) # otherwise add the items as normal
```

Really not sure if that'll work, but I tried to make it group successive indented lines into lists of lists